# Node js program hanging

Tags: javascript, promise

```
defaultAuth
  .getUser("e5TXAefQdgUFtnyM3vIyIbL1ihp2")
  .then(userPromise => {
    console.log(userPromise);
  })
  .then(something => {})
  .catch(something => {});
```

This program hangs forever ; 
however it exits by adding

```
then(something => {
  process.exit();
});
```

is this a defined / correct  behavior or there is a graceful way to solve this

Comment: Is there a larger context to the program? It seems more likely there is something getting stuck at a later stage, and you adding process.exit() kills it before it gets there. Otherwise, this shouldn't hang forever, it should exit itself (if this is the only code in it)

Comment: there is no larger context. This is a full program

Comment: I'd assume that `defaultAuth.getUser("e5TXAefQdgUFtnyM3vIyIbL1ihp2` opens some kind of connection to a database, which stays open until you close it. So does the NodeJS process.

Comment: What does `defaultAuth.getUser()` do? Please post its implementation to provide a [mcve]

Comment: As per other threads in stack overflow I need app.delete I will try and share findings

Comment: @JonasWilms correct. Firebase app.delete is needed

Comment: forvaidya please add a self answer quoting @Jonas suggestion and accept it. In this way everyone can quickly understand your problem and the solution.